# UIScrollView loading an image

Tags: cocoa, image, uiscrollview

i wanted to find an "easy" way to use the pinch/zoom function on my app!
so i decided to use a UIScrollView.
so far so good.

i load my image from an sqlite db like so:

```
        - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
            imageView.image = entity.Aattribute;
        }


    - (void)viewDidLoad {
                self.title = @"Title";

        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
        imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


            myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
            myScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
            myScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.75;
            myScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
            myScrollView.delegate = self;

            [myScrollView addSubview:imageView];


 self.view = myScrollView;



        }


        - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
            return imageView;
        }
```

any help would be appreciated!

thank you for your time!

**EDIT:**
i m just gonna answer my own question here! (i m getting better at this!!! LOL)

up above is the working code. i have edited it so if anyone needs this can refer to it!
thanks for the answers!

Comment: It's fine that you answer your own question, but it's considered courteous to explain what was wrong and to leave the question intact, so people can see what changed between the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This looks mostly correct.  A couple of notes:

- you've misspelled "viewDidLoad".  This could be a side effect of typing it into the browser window.  If it's wrong in your code, then it's certainly not helping things be better.
- `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` is expecting you to return a `UIView`.  `myImage` sounds suspiciously *unlike* a `UIView`.  You should be returning the `imageView` instance variable.  That's what's getting moved around.

**Edit**

[From the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1):

> The UIScrollView class can have a
>   delegate that must adopt the
>   [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate) protocol. For
>   zooming and panning to work, the
>   delegate must implement both
>   [viewForZoomingInScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006923-CH3-SW7): and
>   [scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:);
>   in addition, the maximum
>   ([maximumZoomScale](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/maximumZoomScale)) and minimum (
>   [minimumZoomScale](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/minimumZoomScale)) zoom scale must be
>   different.

So it looks like you still need to implement another delegate method.

Comment: hello there! thank you for your response. the code i wrote was out of my head but i have corrected it by copy/paste from my project.

what happens is that the image is loading BUT no zoom AT ALL!

Comment: hi there. i do adopt the UIScrollView delegate method. however in ALL the tutorials i ve seen noone implements the scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale: etc etc. the sample code works just fine. my code works just fine as long as i do not import my sqlite data image! (i use ImageToDataTransformer) in my xcdatamodel.
this is really weird!

Comment: @treasure if your code works find, unless you're importing the image from sqlite, then why on earth didn't you post the code that's not working?!

Comment: actually this is a not working code!
i said when i use this in the viewdidload method:


 UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.austinbull.com/clonemines.png"]]]];
 [self setMyImage:tempImageView];
 [tempImageView release];

it works ok!

BUT when i use this:

 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        imageView.image = entity.Aattribute;
    }

 to load my image it doesnt!